# How can I add icon at the end of the text using CSS in shiny?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shiny, shinyjs

How can I place icon at the end of the text like in the image and based on the percentage the text will hide and shown instead of that, is it possible to keep the text in the screen?

[image: Kindly refer the image]

File myloader.html, to put in the app folder:

```
 <div class="myloader">
      <h1>
        <span></span>
      </h1>
    </div>
```

File myloader.css, to put in the www subfolder:

```
    .myloader {
  text-align:center; 
  align-items: center;
}

.myloader > h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: blue;
}

.myloader > h1 > span::before {
  content: "";
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    content: "Analyzing", ;
  }

  90% {
    content: "Fetching Data"....;
    
  }
  100% {
    content: "Fetching Items!";
  }
}
```

And the Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycustomloader)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  withLoader(
    plotOutput("plot"),
    type = "html",
    loader = "myloader"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$go
    x <- NULL
    for(. in 1:30000){
      x <- c(x, runif(1))
    }
    plot(x)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could you give more explanation of what it is you want to do as the image does not correspond to the code you give. The code would appear to show each phrase in the same place, not as a list as shown in the image.

Comment: ya @AHaworth my code will show the phrase in the same place but instead of that i need to show the text as a list like in the image

Comment: is it possible to modify the above code or any other reference would be helpful @AHaworth